# Conditional Highlighting with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In this example https://jsfiddle.net/erv79u0w/, when "Select All" is clicked, all the respective values are highlighted on the table.

Is it possible to highlight *ONLY* the values existing together in the *same row* on the table. As an example, the first values (A,B,X,Y) when Selected with "Select All", only the values that appear in the same row together should be highlighted. And in this case, it is only the second row on the table. So only the values on the second row should be highlighted.

> The cells *not* in the same row shouldn't be highlighted like in the image below.

[image]

```js
$('.selector').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', check);
});

$('.all').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', all);
});

function all(event) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked", "checked");
  } else {
    $("input:checkbox(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked", "");
  }

  //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");

  check(event);
}

function check(event) {
  var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function() {
    return this.name
  }).get()
  $('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
  }).addClass("highlight")
  if ($(this).is(".selector"))
    $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: #9ac99d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar1">

      <div id="container">
        <div id="sidebar1">
          <h3>Parameters:</h3>
          <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />Select All</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="A" class="selector" />A</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="B" class="selector" />B</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="X" class="selector" />X</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Y" class="selector" />Y</label>
          </form>
          <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />Select All</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="K" class="selector" />K</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="J" class="selector" />J</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="M" class="selector" />M</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="T" class="selector" />T</label>
          </form>
        </div>
      
      <div id="mainContent">
        <h3 align="right">&nbsp;</h3>
        <div>
          <table width="200" border="1">
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>M</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>K</td>
              <td>J</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
              <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>J</td>
              <td>T</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td> X</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>X</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>K</td>
              <td>Q</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>T</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>M</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>T</td>
              <td>K</td>
              <td>J</td>
              <td>Z</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you add an image of what is the current render and what is the desired one? it's not so clear

Comment: @Andreas - question was edited and this was fixed

Comment: please be crystal clear what exactly you want to achieve. this question is **very** unclear and on the border of get closed..

Comment: I have created a snippet for you by clicking the `<>` button.

Comment: @mplungjan - I don't understand. highlight what? all the cells? there are many rows, which ones should be highlighted?? your comment is the opposite of clearing this up :/

Comment: I cleaned the code on jsfiddle. I will do so here now too.

Comment: Okay just use the property `rowIndex` of DOM. Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) and compare the `rowIndex` of all `td` before highlighting

Comment: I slightly agree it is unclear. If I click "Y" which "Y"s are highlighted? Only the 2 "Y"s in the last row? or do the other Ys get another colour?

Comment: I edited my post, and gave an example to make it clearer. Check it please.

Comment: Put your A,B,X,Y into an array. For each form, loop over that array, and use `.has()` to see if that form has checkboxes with those names. Use a counter or a boolean flag, so that afterwards you know, does this particular form contain all of those checkboxes. If so, check them, otherwise, move on to the next form ...

Comment: @mplungjan I mean for group highlighting with "Select All".

Comment: Answer to your question: "Is it possible to highlight them if they are only present in the same row?" answer is "Yes". 
"Is it possible with the code I wrote?" Answer is "not so easily".
So please make a try selecting elements by their row, and not directly the by the `td`. Otherwise you're asking us to rewrite completely your logic in order to do that.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand what you meant with  "So please make a try selecting elements from his row, and not directly the from the td".

Comment: @Max in your jQuery code you select directly the `td` => `$('td')`. You will have your life easier for this functionality if you select the rows and then elaborate the cells children of that row `$('tr')`

Comment: Thanks. I will check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.compare = function(testArr) {
  if (this.length != testArr.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    if (this[i].compare) { //To test values in nested arrays
      if (!this[i].compare(testArr[i])) return false;
    } else if (this[i] !== testArr[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
$(document).on('click', '.all', function() {
  $('#mainContent table tr td').removeClass('highlight');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input.selector').prop('checked', false);
  }
  $('input[name=SelectAll]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('form').find('input.selector').prop('checked', true);
      processAllClick($(this));
    } else {
      processIndividualClick($(this));
    }
  });
});
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function() {
  $('#mainContent table tr td').removeClass('highlight');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input.all').prop('checked', false);
  }
  $('input[name=SelectAll]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      processAllClick($(this));
    } else {
      processIndividualClick($(this));
    }
  });
});

function processIndividualClick(input) {
  $(input).closest('form').find('input.selector:checked').each(function() {
    $('td:contains(' + $(this).attr('name') + ')').addClass('highlight');
  });
}

function processAllClick(input) {
  var elems = [];
  $(input).closest('form').find('input.selector:checked').each(function() {
    elems.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  $('#mainContent table tr').each(function() {
    var child = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      if ($.inArray($(this).text(), elems) != -1)
        child.push($(this).text());
    });
    if (elems.sort().compare(child.sort())) {
      for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() == child[i]) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: #9ac99d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar1">

    <div id="container">
      <div id="sidebar1">
        <h3>Parameters:</h3>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />Select All</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="A" class="selector" />A</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="B" class="selector" />B</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="X" class="selector" />X</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Y" class="selector" />Y</label>
        </form>
        <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />Select All</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="K" class="selector" />K</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="J" class="selector" />J</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="M" class="selector" />M</label>
          <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="T" class="selector" />T</label>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="mainContent">
        <h3 align="right">&nbsp;</h3>
        <div>
          <table width="200" border="1">
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>M</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>K</td>
              <td>J</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
              <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>J</td>
              <td>T</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td> X</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>X</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>K</td>
              <td>Q</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>T</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>M</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>T</td>
              <td>K</td>
              <td>J</td>
              <td>Z</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

All click event is handled here

Comment: This is great. You changed the whole jquery code. I will need some time to understand your code. I will use it. Thanks a lot. https://jsfiddle.net/max33/yb81rrpy/

Comment: I'm updating my code with small changes, so as it handle individual clicks also. Hope you have the backup in jsfiddle

Comment: ok, thanks. I was ready to give up on individual clicks. https://jsfiddle.net/34j92qjk/